# Can’t install Ubuntu 18.04, my install is completely different to last time!

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, usb-installation

Recently my computer running Ubuntu 18.04 crashed completely and I had to force power off the laptop by holding down the power button. When I tried to turn it back on the screen was completely black and was failing to boot. Error messages would repeat. I presumed the OS had crashed and wasn’t operable any more, so I took my Live USB that I had used only 2 days ago to set up Ubuntu for the first time and plugged it back in and started to reboot Ubuntu again. Everything went fine until I got past the updates and other software section. Next I got a screen I didn’t get before. It says:

Your installation medium is on `/dev/sda1`. You will not be able to create, delete, or resize partitions on this disk, but you may be able to install existing partitions there.

Underneath this message, there is a list of devices

```
Device Type Mount-point Format  Size    Used  System

/dev/sda
/dev/sda1               fat     3216173 2014
/dev/sda2                       0mb           Unknown
```

This didn’t happen last time and I have no idea what to do. I tried changing dev sda1 fat32 to ext 2 and mount point / but it just said the ext2 creation.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)-** How recent is this machine?  Looks like a dying HDD. what is the output of `smartctl --all /dev/sda` ?  Please [edit] your question to provide that info there instead of here in the comments.  Then leave a message @Fabby

Comment: So I went into try Ubuntu to access the terminal to input smartctl —all devices /dev/sda but it prompted me to install smartmontools. I did, but as soon as I had typed in the Y key for yes, I got a prompt/pop up telling me to select the mail server configuration type that best meets my needs, followed by empty space and then:                     No configuration: should be chosen to leave the current configuration unchanged. (This is followed by some information on how mail is treated on my machine. Sorry again, but I can’t seem to click enter or proceed or exit after this screen without

Comment: Without force exiting by pressing the red X in the top right of the terminal. Sorry, I ran out of characters there and had to string it into this comment. I was thinking, should I just try to completely reset the laptop and remove everything from it and try to boot Linux from my usb from there? Are there corrupted files still in place? I am not worried about losing anything on the laptop as all important things are on usb’s.

Comment: Without more information, I cannot tell you.  Yes, `smartctl` is in the `smartmontools` package.

Comment: I’m not currently able to install that though :/

Comment: Boot from a live USB and install it there.